# Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 beta 15 and in one of my templates I did that :

```
 <a  data-value="{{i18n.currentLanguage}}" > {{i18n.translate('Language')}}</a>
```

But, I get this exception

```
angular2.dev.js:23925 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise):Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known native property ("<div>
<a  [ERROR ->]data-value="{{i18n.currentLanguage}}">{{i18n.translate('Language')}}</a>
```

So, is there any idea how to solve that ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use attribute binding instead of the default property binding

```
<a  attr.data-value="{{i18n.currentLanguage}}" > {{i18n.translate('Language')}}</a>
```

or

```
<a  [attr.data-value]="i18n.currentLanguage" > {{i18n.translate('Language')}}</a>
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine now :)